# Jquery UI DIV auto resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQUERY UI LIBRARY, and I have simple JQUERY COMMAND

```
$(".div1").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

$(".link1").click(
    function () {
        $(".div1").dialog('open');
        $(".div1").css("width", "500px");
        return false;
    }
);

.table   {width:500px}

<div class="div1" title="New Vindow">
   <div class="table">
   </div>
</div>
```

When I clicking link1 opens a new vindow DIV1. It is ok. But I can note give the width to this vindow. Above i have written 500px, but it does not work, the size almost 350 px. Inside div1 I have another div, the width of div is 500px. So, How can I change the width of div1 to see everything on vindow? I checked jquery-ui.min, nothing found about width. May be I need to write extra commands? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `width` option in [dialog default options](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```
$(".div1").dialog({   width: 500; });

$(".div1").dialog('open');
```